# Python: Why using asfreq() is dropping my last row of data?

Tags: python, time-series, datetimeindex

I can not figure it out why when I am using pandas asfreq() method it is droping my last row of data.

```
data = rental_2012_09_to_2020_06.copy()

data.drop(columns='postcode', inplace=True)

data.columns = ['Quarter_End', 'Rental_Median']

data.index = pd.to_datetime(data['Quarter_End'])

data = data.asfreq(freq='Q', method='ffill')

data.drop(columns='Quarter_End', inplace=True)

data.info()
data.head()
```

Result running with above code:

[image: result with above code]

Result running commenting the `asfreq()` line:
[image: result withouth freq()]

Any ideas? I read the documentation but it does not give details about this behaviour. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You resampled your time-series dataframe with quarterly frequency:

> ```
> data = data.asfreq(freq='Q', method='ffill')
> ```

According to [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases), the `Q` frequency alias stands for "quarter end frequency". The first entry in the original dataframe is from 1 September 2012, and the last one is from 1 June 2020.

I'm guessing that `asfreq` resamples the time range such that the resampled range falls within the original range (but as far as I can see, this isn't documented). Since the first quarter end after 01/09/2012 is 30/09/2012, and the last quarter end before 01/06/2020 is 31/03/2020, the resulting date range is 30/09/2012 to 31/03/2020 (both inclusive), with quarterly frequency, resulting in 31 samples. The fact that this is exactly one less sample than the original dataframe is merely a coincidence (in the sense that it depends on the original datetime range).

**Edit:** By digging around in pandas source code, I've found where exactly this behaviour is defined/documented. Buried deep in the call graph of `asfreq`, there is the generator `generate_range` (specifically, [`pandas.core.arrays.datetimes.generate_range`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2a7d3326dee660824a8433ffd01065f8ac37f7d6/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py#L2365-L2440), as of v1.1.2), which is the core functionality defining the datetime values in a range `[start, end]` with a certain time offset between values (i.e. frequency).

```py
def generate_range(start=None, end=None, periods=None, offset=BDay()): ...
```

Its docstring specifies:

> ```
> Notes
> -----
> * [...]
> * If both start and end are specified, the returned dates will
> satisfy start <= date <= end.
> ```

---

**Response to comments**

I think you might be misunderstanding what `asfreq` does. It does not simply shift around values to the nearest time that falls on the boundary of the frequency; instead it creates a whole new series, using the data from the original as if it had been sampled at certain timestamps (as specified by the frequency). That is, you're [*resampling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample-rate_conversion) your data.

Try removing the `method='ffil'` argument from the call: you'll see that the new series will be all `NaN`s (except in those cases where the timestamp coincides with a timestamp from the original series)—this is because it doesn't know what the value of a sample should be at an unknown timestamp.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dtm

index = pd.DatetimeIndex(data=[
    dtm.datetime(2019, 12, 1),
    dtm.datetime(2020, 2, 17),
    dtm.datetime(2020, 3, 31),
    dtm.datetime(2020, 6, 1),
])

series = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=index)
```

```
>>> series
2019-12-01    1
2020-02-17    2
2020-03-31    3
2020-06-01    4
dtype: int64

>>> series.asfreq('Q')
2019-12-31    NaN
2020-03-31    3.0
Freq: Q-DEC, dtype: float64
```

This makes perfect sense if you think about it: how is `pandas` supposed to know what the value was on `2019-12-31` if there is no recorded value for that date in the original data?

Of course, having a series full of `NaN`s isn't very useful, so we need to find a way to *infer* the missing data from what's available. That's where filling methods like `method='ffil'` (copy the last available value) or `method='bfil'` (copy the next available value) come into play.

Now, going back to your question: the only reason there isn't a record for 2020-06-30 is because of what the docstring of `generate_range` above specifies:

> [...] the returned dates will satisfy `start <= date <= end`

i.e., the transformed datetime range will always fall *within* the original range, and 2020-06-30 falls *outside* the range (since the `end` of the original range is 2020-06-01).

Again, this also makes sense taking into account what we have discussed just now: usually you want to infer missing values in your resampled series (using values from your original series), and it's always easier (and safer) to *interpolate* (i.e. guess what the value would be at a timestep between two other values), than to *extrapolate* (i.e. guess values outside of the original range, either before the start or after the end), and the former is only guaranteed if you keep the new, resampled range within the original range—not to mention that `'ffil'` and `'bfil'` both require this condition in order to work properly (you can't forward-fill the first value if it comes before `start` and you can't backwards-fill the last value if it comes after `end`).

If this is not the behaviour you want, and instead you want to simply shift the timesteps, you have to do something else entirely. You can add an offset to the index, for example:

```py
index = pd.date_range(
    dtm.datetime(2019, 9, 1), 
    dtm.datetime(2020, 6, 1), 
    freq=pd.DateOffset(months=3)
)

series = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=index)
```

```
>>> index
DatetimeIndex(['2019-09-01', '2019-12-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-06-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='<DateOffset: months=3>')

>>> index + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd()
DatetimeIndex(['2019-09-30', '2019-12-31', '2020-03-31', '2020-06-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='<DateOffset: months=3>')
```

Comment: Hello Anakhand, I really appreciate your time looking into this. I cant believe that you had to dig in that much; I thought I was missing something more evident. The original data is quarterly. Thus, the value from 01/03/2020 went to 30/03/2020. The row that is being dropped, is dated 01/06/2020. Frequency tag 'Q' indeed goes to the end of the month/quarter; I couldnt understand why was not sending that value to the 30/06/2020 instead of dropping it. I ended up solving it by creating a new timeseries in the range and predefined freq, assigning it as index and then dropping the original column.

Comment: thank you very much! Your answer its really clear and complete. I really appreciate it. I understand now what 2 different considerations where in palce and avoiding the result I expected (the ffil/bfil interpolation + my date being outside the range). Thank you also for the proposed solutions, I came across the .offsets.MonthEnd() but I thought it wasnt as a tudy solution as just creating a new time series range. I will go back to your suggestion! Thanks again.